# Installed Ubuntu on top of Windows 7 Parition, thus lost an important file!

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, data-recovery, testdisk, photorec

**Hi there.**

I had win 10 and 7 installed on dual boot, then i decided to download and install UBUNTU, in the installation process, i chose to install it on top of the win 7 partition, so it had to erase all its data then proceeded to install ubuntu, everything went fine, until today i noticed i had one small IMPORTANT file that i forgot to back up, but now it's long gone among the other win 7 partition's data.
I did read about softwares like Test disk PhotoRec, ubuntu rescue remix, but i did not know how to use them, because my file were not deleted from trash can, it's a partition that has been be erased.

**Please Help me!**

Comment: Your important file has probably been overwritten. There isn't anything you can do. Installing Ububntu / Linux on a partition overwrites most of the data in it, making th e chances of recovery-programs to find anything almost zero. Important files should always be on a backup.

Comment: Windows typically writes at the beginning of a partition. Linux ext4 writes randomly throughout entire partition. So larger partition and smaller file may have a chance. But photorec requires hours, depending on size and only recovers by file type, or extension, not full file name. I use photorec on smaller partition. It took overnight to run and copy to another drive. But then it took me weeks (not full time) to review every file. Lots of grep & sorting. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step Learned better backups are important.

Comment: Well, i did use photorec, it actually restored my files but not all of them, it seems to have recovered files i deleted years ago, but now the one im looking for which is a .dat file that gives me access to my crypto wallet.